# CFSearch not returning results when using criteria

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfsearch

I followed the steps from [Ray Camden's website](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/11/1/Some-tips-for-working-with-Data-Import-Handlers-in-ColdFusion-10#c5FB2381E-E361-4453-99BCFB2F2097BF62) to use the data import handlers for indexing a collection. My collection is being populated but when I try to use `cfsearch` to return results it comes back empty if I add a criteria to the search. Without a criteria results are returned.

Here is the `cfsearch` tag I am using - has anyone else had similar issue and if so how did you resolve it?

```
<cfsearch name="mySearch"
          collection="FORD OEM"
          maxRows="200"
          criteria="window"
          type="dismax">
```

**Update:**

I was able to make some progress. If do searches like this, where I specify the column name in the criteria, they return results. (I was unable to get any of the [examples on the adobe web site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WS82937B1B-240F-4850-B376-5FD9F911E5E5.html) to work.)

```
<cfsearch name="mySearch" 
         collection ="FORD OEM" 
         maxRows="200" 
         criteria="description:window" 
         type="standard" />
```

Comment: FYI, moved above comment into main question for better visibility, so the above can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when a column is not specified in the criteria, cfsearch by default looks for a column named contents which I had not created in the dataconfig.xml or referenced in the schema.xml file.  When I added the contents column it worked as expected.